# Error in filling a datagrid with a query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a `DataGridView` and I add my query to this, when executed my query throws this error:

> *The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query*

This my query:

```
        SELECT
               B.SettingKey, 'SysSettingsDep' AS TableName,
               B.SettingValue, B.SettingDesc
        FROM   SysCustomer AS A INNER JOIN
               SysSettingsDep AS B ON A.SettingKey = B.SettingKey
        UNION
        SELECT C.SettingKey, 'SysSettingsMachine' AS TableName,
               C.SettingValue, C.SettingDesc

        FROM    SysCustomer AS A INNER JOIN
                SysSettingsMachine AS C ON A.SettingKey = C.SettingKey
        UNION
        SELECT  D.SettingKey, 'SysSettings' AS TableName,
                D.SettingValue, D.SettingDesc
        FROM    SysCustomer AS A INNER JOIN SysSettings AS D ON
                A.SettingKey = D.SettingKey
```

help me to solve this,

tnx

Comment: How exactly are you adding the query to the datagridview?

Comment: in DataGridView Tasks Choice Add Query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood it appears that the TableAdapter/DataTable that was created initially used a different query ( the base query ) and it seems like the new query that you are using is fetching a different resulting schema and hence the mismatch.

Try to use a new TableAdapter for your DataSet and not the old one....